# Oracle update a table where the phones are horizontal from another table where the phones are vertical

Tags: oracle, multiple-columns

In ORACLE I am trying to update a table where the phones are horizontal from the data in another table where the phones are vertical.

I have tried MERGE and UNPIVOT, but these are not working due to the table I am trying to update has many phones, but the data I need to update it with only has one phonenum.

Some accounts have 3 phonenums, some only have 1 phonenum  (Vertical-get data from this table)

```
TableA
phone_num
Account_num
Phone_type

1234567890, 123, CELL
8165558877, 123, CELL
9135889685, 123, LAND
8885551212, 444, CELL
9995551212, 888, CELL
```

---

```
TableB (Horizontal - Update data in this table)
account_num
phone1_num
phone2_num
phone3_num
phone1_type
phone2_type
phone3_type

123,1234567890,8165558877,9135889685, UNKNOWN, UNKNOWN, CELL
444,8885551212,,,UNKNOWN,,
888,9995551212,,,UNKNOWN,,
```

Final Result should be

```
123,1234567890,8165558877,9135889685, CELL, CELL, LAND
444,8885551212,,,CELL,,
888,9995551212,,,CELL,,
```

Comment: What?  Please format the data, as it is unreadable.

Comment: What do you need table B for? All information you need is in table A which is normalized, as opposed to table B which is not, and which gives you headache. What will you do when someone gets 4th or 9th phone number? Alter table B and add new 2 or new 10 columns? When will it end? In my opinion, forget about it and use table A.

Comment: @Littlefoot is 100% correct in his assessment of your data design.  In addition, for future reference, please read and heed https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you have tried something, then you should have some code. But why you didn't post it? What "doesn't work" means? Do you have any errors or the result is not what you want? Also please post your data DDL and insert statements or format it properly

Comment: I agree with Littlefoot and EdStevens about the wrong design if that is not just your homework, but even if that's your homework, I agree with astenx - you need to show what exactly you have done already